# howto use ui.bootstrap.datepickerPopup with html form

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using `ui.bootstrap.datepickerPopup` with angular forms, but i also want to use it with ASP.Net html forms. If i use an MVC EditorTemplate as below

```
//Date.cshtml
@{ 
        var prop = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
        var required = ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired;
<p class="input-group"  >
    <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" id="@prop" name="@prop" ng-model="@prop" @required class="form-control" ng-required="true" is-open="@(prop)Open"  init-date="new Date()"  value="@ViewData.Model"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="@(prop)Open = !@(prop)Open"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>
    }
```

I can select a date and it correctly posts. However when i try and edit a form with an existing Date value, i cannot get it to pre populate the date. Can the init-date be passed inline? I've tried to test this in a plunkr here. http://plnkr.co/edit/glVfsqNVst11IxRvF3tJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it through `datepicker-options` as shown below.

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" id="@prop" name="@prop" ng-
model="@prop" @required class="form-control" ng-required="true" is-
open="@(prop)Open"  datepicker-options="{minDate:'@ViewData.DateOptions'}"  value="@ViewData.Model"/>
```

Comment: I tried using  datepicker-options="{initDate: '2015-04-20'}"  to test or in razor   datepicker-options="{initDate: '@ViewData.Model'}" and it didn't seem to work

Comment: Use `minDate: new Date(),` instead.

Comment: If i try minDate i get angular.js:13424 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Date' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 15 of the expression [{minDate: new Date('19/01/2016')}] starting at [Date('19/01/2016')}

Comment: and if it worked wouldnt it restrict my starting date?

Comment: It defines the minimum available date and requires a `Javascript Date object`.

Comment: well no luck using that syntax. As per error above. Tried with and without the Value specified, also tried ng-init and no luc

Comment: try like this : `minDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),`

Comment: That gives me the exact same error as above  datepicker-options="{minDate: new Date(2020, 5, 21)}". If you try it in the plunkr and open the devtools you can see,.

Comment: can you give me that plunk ?

Comment: can't you fill the data for this control using Ajax request ?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead ... bootstrap 3 datepicker version 4.  You can set the default value as well

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

code snippets from the site ...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
                    defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
                    disabledDates: [
                        moment("12/25/2013"),
                        new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                        "11/22/2013 00:53"
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

datepicker init has a bug... see this forum..
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2331